# Pydoop Error of No Module

Tags: python, hadoop

I am running a simple pydoop program to count the words in "alice.txt". However getting a weird error. I am not sure whether some module is missing or code is wrong.

Pydoop Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import pydoop

def mapper(_,text,writer):
        for word in text.split():
                writer.emit(word,"1")

def reducer(word,icounts,writer):
        writer.emit(word,sum(map(int,icounts)))

def combiner(word,icounts,writer):
        writer.count('combiner calls', 1)
        reducer(word,icounts,writer)
```

Steps to mount and run the pydoop code:

```
pydoop script -c combiner wc.py alice.txt a.txt
```

Error :

```
ImportError: No module named _hdfs_2_0_0_cdh_4_3_0
```

Comment: Looks like pydoop wasn't properly installed

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Unfortunately working on the shared , company  machine and have "no" control over change in installation. any clue about how to resolve it.

Comment: Install on a virtual machine, perhaps. In the worst case, you might have to call the sysadmin

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks.... sysadmin option seems to be the resort here.... Thanks for your time also